# Scrum Template or Update for TFS2010 supporting VS2012, Unable to Associate Coded UI with Test Case

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, coded-ui-tests, scrum

I am using TFS 2010 with Scrum template. I am creating a Coded UI test cases using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and Checked in in TFS. Later I created a manual test cases using Test manager and when I am trying to associate it with Coded UI . What it seems that my TFS Scrum template is not fully supporting all the functionality like I am unable to see button with ellipsis (…) sign on ASSOCIATED AUTOMATION tab due to which I am unable to associate it .

Does Scrum provide any support or template upgrade or a new one for Visual Studio 2012 on TFS 2010 ?

OR

Is there any thing else that I am missing ?

[Issue screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPnwS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are trying to create the association in Microsoft Test Manager, and not in the Visual Studio IDE.

Open the test case inside Visual Studio (and not the Test Manager). From there the ellipse should appear and you should be able to create the association. You cannot create the association from within MTM, it must be done from within VS.

Comment: I got issue solved . Actually we were using SCRUM process template and TFS2012 so the supportive things were not there . In order to solve the issue is Modified template xml and added control there and it worked .